# Check dictionary for duplicate items

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary but there is a lot of instances where duplicate data could be added to it. I am trying to prevent duplicate keys or values from being added. However, with this code I still get "An item with the same key has already been added". I want to only add new keys and values to the dictionary if they have not been added to the dictionary yet.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.Count; ++i) 
{
    if (!webidsAndXPaths.ContainsKey(nodes[i].Id) || !webidsAndXPaths.ContainsValue(nodes[i].XPath)) // if the key or value does not exist then add it to the dictionary
    webidsAndXPaths.Add(nodes[i].Id, nodes[i].XPath); // now we put the data in a dictionary <key = id, value = xpath>
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right data structure here?

Comment: No, I'm not, lol. Want to get two pieces of data and write them into a database. Sometimes the data is redundant so if it tries to add it to the dictionary then it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you run into an item with the same *key* but a different *value* then it will still try and insert it. If you *really* want to prevent duplicate values then you'd need to use `&&` instead:

```
if (!webidsAndXPaths.ContainsKey(nodes[i].Id) &&
    !webidsAndXPaths.ContainsValue(nodes[i].XPath)) // if the key AND value do not exist then add it to the dictionary
```

But preventing duplicate *values* seems like an odd requirement for a dictionary.  `Dictionary` only requires that `Key`s are unique - it has no problem with duplicate `Value`s.  Perhaps you only want unique key/value pairs?

If duplicate *keys* is your only concern than this would be a proper method:

```
if (!webidsAndXPaths.ContainsKey(nodes[i].Id)) // if the key does not exist then add it to the dictionary
```

Another option is to just *set* the value regardless of whether it exists or not.  The only difference would be that the *last* value found would "win" instead of the *first*:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.Count; ++i) 
{
    webidsAndXPaths[nodes[i].Id] = nodes[i].XPath; 
}
```

Using the indexer (`[]`) does *not* throw an exception if the key exists, but will overwrite the *value* for that key (or add it if the key doesn't exist)

Comment: yes, it's okay for the value to be duplicate as long as every entry is unique then it works.

Comment: If by "entry" you mean "key" then yes.  There is no build-in mechanism within `Dictionary` to ensure unique key-value _pairs_.

Comment: @DStanley, that's right, not with a `Dictionary` at least. However, a `Tuple` actually does it, albeit maybe by happenstance :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using `||` which means that if the value doesn't exists in your dictionary that statement will evaluate to *true* even if the key has been already added.Either use separate if statements or use *AND* (`&&`) instead of `OR`.

```
if (!webidsAndXPaths.ContainsKey(nodes[i].Id) &&
     !webidsAndXPaths.ContainsValue(nodes[i].XPath))
{
    webidsAndXPaths.Add(nodes[i].Id, nodes[i].XPath);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check only for the key, not the value. Because there is a chance that `ContainsValue` may return `false`, but the same key was added already, In that case you'll get the exception.

```
if (!webidsAndXPaths.ContainsKey(nodes[i].Id))
     webidsAndXPaths.Add(nodes[i].Id, nodes[i].XPath);
```

If you need keys and values to be unique, You can create custom **immutable** struct which holds two properties (Id, Xpath), then add it as a key.

Update1:

It seems you're just worrying about exceptions, It is worth noting that duplicate values will **not** throw exception but duplicate keys will.

In case you get duplicate key, if you decide to use the latest arrived value you can do something like this.

```
 webidsAndXPaths[nodes[i].Id] = nodes[i].XPath;
```

This won't throw exception, it will overwrite the value if already same key exist.

Comment: So only keys have to be unique, but values could be duplicate?

Comment: @ma3str0, yes. That is what makes a key a key: being unique and distinguishable from any other key. This does not apply to values, hence you can put the same value/same object under different keys in a dictionary.

Comment: @ma3str0 So you need to prevent duplicate keys and duplicate values as well?

Comment: I think as long as the pair is unique then everything will be good, I basically just don't want redundant data to throw exceptions and stop the program from executing.

Comment: @ma3str0 See if my Update1 helps

Answer (score 1):

If what you really need is unique key value pairs, I think you want to use a `Tuple` here. You might have something like this:

```
var kvpList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
```

and then you can just do this:

```
var newTuple = Tuple.Create(nodes[i].Id, nodes[i].XPath);
if (!kvpList.Contains(newTuple))
    kvpList.Add(newTuple);
```

This works because a Tuple's default comparison is by value.